# Disk faulty..but working?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm on linux slackware
Smartctl said

```
smartctl -H /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.8.4] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
Failed Attributes:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   010    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 51496
```

dmesg report no error

```
[161040.849645] ...........ready
[161051.091428] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[161051.091435] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[161051.091896] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[161051.091905] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[161051.092126] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[161051.157726]  sdc: sdc1
[161051.159108] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[161401.864311] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Currently i'm writing data on disk,no error.

Smartctl -a report this

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.8.4] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Desktop HDD.15
Device Model:     ST4000DM000-2AE166
Serial Number:    WDH0PD56
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 09d09cac0
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5980 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Nov 10 04:56:26 2016 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  73) The previous self-test completed having
                    a test element that failed and the test
                    element that failed is not known.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  581) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 613) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x10a5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   071   043   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       12590177
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   095   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   010    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 51496
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       5576438
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18 (102 172 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1521
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3 3 3
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   069   068   040    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 30/31)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       161
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   031   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (0 18 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   007   006   000    Old_age   Always       -       7664
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   007   006   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7664
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18h+09m+16.910s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5995776308
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3798683410

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1521 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1521 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16 hours (0 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:22.556  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:22.556  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:22.556  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:22.556  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:22.556  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1520 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16 hours (0 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:19.284  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:19.284  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:19.283  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:19.283  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:19.283  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1519 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16 hours (0 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 08 50 68 09 40 00      05:53:15.673  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 01 08 68 09 40 00      05:53:15.663  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:15.663  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:15.663  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:15.653  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1518 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16 hours (0 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:12.273  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:12.262  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:12.253  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:12.243  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:12.243  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1517 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16 hours (0 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 53 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:06.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:06.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:06.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:06.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:53:06.819  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: unknown failure    90%        18         0
# 2  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%        18         0
# 3  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%        18         0
# 4  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%        17         0

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Question is..is broken?Or what else?

Comment: How is the output not clear? The drive is failing, the relocated sector count is over threshold, which only happens when the a sector is marked bad and then moved a "spare" sector. BACKUP THE DATA ON THE DRIVE IMMEDIATELY!!! Then write zeros to the drive and do an off-line long self-test to verify the results.

Comment: Reallocated sectors means parts of your drive are becoming unable to reliably store data. This will inevitably escalate to failure and data loss. **Back up the data and replace the drive as soon as possible.**

Comment: bwDraco,add comment as answer so i can vote and we close.